# Polygon Network Fraud Proofs - State change reversal

Tags: sidechain, layer-2, polygon

After doing some surface reading about the Polygon L2 side-chain. I was interested in *what actually happens if a successful fraud proof is submitted?*.

> To enhance the security of the transactions, Matic Network also provides Fraud Proofs on the mainchain. The mechanism enables any individual on the mainchain to submit the details of the transactions which he/she thinks is fraudulent. If the challenge is successful, the stakes of the parties involved in the fraud are slashed and the challenger receives the slashed funds as an incentive for detecting the fraud. This can be considered as an always-running high reward bounty program for any parties who wish to investigate the veracity of the transactions on the Matic Network.
> [1]

It sounds great, but does the state change on the side chain get reversed to reflect the *actual* side chain state?

Let's consider the following situation:

1. `User X` exchanges `10 token Ys` for `10 token Zs` on a Polygon DEX.
2. Collusion occurs between 2/3 of the networks stakers.
3. The checkpoint for the main chain states that `User X` only received `5 Z tokens` for `10 Y tokens`.
4. Valid fraud proof is submitted.
5. Stakers get slashed
6. ..... Does `user X` get the extra `5 Z tokens` they were promised? Does the checkpoint that the fraud proof proposer submitted fix the state of the side chain on the main chain (In effect, replaces the old, incorrect one)?

It would be great to see come Solidity unit tests that I can take a look at. Particularly tests that demonstrate this fraud proof feature. e.g. https://github.com/maticnetwork/contracts/blob/a5b2022c5387bae3424a6c83635647e920b4dfb5/contracts/proofs/TxValidator.sol#L15-L54

[1] - https://medium.com/matic-network/what-is-matic-network-466a2c493ae1

Comment: Not sure if this is the place to be asking layer 2 questions. Please let me know if there is a more relevant forum.